# Removing External site content from search index in SP2013

Tags: enterprise-search

I have crawled external site https://some.com in sharepoint 2013. Now how to delete or remove this external site content from the index. 
Can we do it using crawl rules ?

Comment: Please clarify that how you have crawled the content. Did you create as separate content source?? If yes you can delete the content source.. Or you can create crawl rule to exclude the contents and start full crawl.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process to remove an item from Search index.

If you dont want that site in search then remove the url from the content source.

[Remove an item from the search index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/JJ219587.aspx)

- Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an
  administrator for the Search service application.
- On the SharePoint Central Administration home page, in the
  Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
- On the Manage Search Applications page, click the Search service
  application.
- On the Search Administration page, in the Diagnostics section, click
  Crawl Log.
- On the Crawl Log page, click URL View.
- Do one of the following:

  - If you know the URL of the item that you want to remove, type the URL in the box.
  - If you do not know the URL of the item that you want to remove, search for it by using the filters Content Source, Status or Message.
- Click Search.
- Find and point to the URL of the item that you want to remove, click
  the arrow and then click Remove the item from the Index.
- In the confirmation dialog that appears, click OK to confirm that you
  want to remove the item from the index.
- Verification: the text Removed from the search index by Admin appears
  under the URL in the crawl log.

Comment: It's not about individual URL, they can exclude from crawl rule or delete the entire content source.